# Database lookup in Talend

Tags: sql, lookup, talend

In my talned job I am copying data from Excel to SQL table.
For this job to maintain the foreign key constraint I had to do a look up before copying the data.

The task goes like this.
I have to copy data in Table2 (id keys value).
My excel sheet has data for id and keys column. Table 1 has two columns id and value.

For value column's data I want to look at Table1's corresponding entry with the id of the current record in Table2. I have to copy the data from Table1's value column to Table2's value column.

Excel (id 1 2 3, keys a b c)
Table_1 (id 1 2 3, value 123 456 789)
desired output: Table_2 (id 1 2 3, keys a b c, value 123 456 789)
current output: Table_2 (id 1 2 3, keys a b c, value null null null)

How do I properly map this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of your two tables as they are and how you'd like the result to look? As it is, it sounds like you want to make table 1 look like table 2 and I'm guessing that's not what you want.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear with my question. I needed to do database lookup to keep the foreign key constraint. I found the methood here to do so.. http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2009/12/performing-lookups-and-transformations-with-talend/

Comment: I still need to see an example of your two tables and an example output to help you here. You don't have to use real data for this.

Comment: I was being able to solve my issues with the help of the thing explained in that link.
I dont remember exactly but my data was like this...
Excel sheet: ID 1 2 3, Value 50 60 70.
Table 2: ID 1 2 3, Name x y z, Key A B C.
Output Table 1: ID 1 2 3, Key A B C, Value 50 60 70.

Comment: I have added my question and have provided the screenshots.
I am not getting the 'value' column values.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the job up exactly as needs to be done really so it's not your job layout that's the problem here.

If you're expecting every record in your Excel document to have a matching record in your database table then you should use an `inner join` condition in your tMap join like so:

[image: Join Condition in tMap]

And this then allows you to have an output that grabs everything that isn't joining (which is your issue here):

[image: Join Rejects configuration]

This should show you everything in your source (not lookup) file that isn't matching. I suspect that everything is failing to match on your join condition (essentially `WHERE ExcelDoc.id = Table.Id`) even if it looks like it should. This could be down to a mismatch of datatypes as they are read into Talend (so the Java/Talend datatypes such as int/Integer or String rather than the DB types) or because one of your `id` columns has extraneous whitespace padding.

If you find that your `id` column in one of your sources does in fact have any padding then you should be able to convert it in a previous step before your join or even just make the transformation in the join:

[image: Transform inputs in the join itself]

The only other thing I'd recommend is that you name your flows between components (just click on them to change the name), especially when you are joining anything in a tMap.

Comment: I tried .trim(), but its not working.
So I am assuming that the problem is with data types.
My Table_2's id and value column has string datatype and VARCHAR as their DBtype, as defined in Schema.

Comment: Properly profile both your datasets before you attempt to join it. The trim was simply an example for why something that appears to be a match for a record in the joining table wouldn't be matched. If you use the data profiling perspective you should be able to build an analysis of your data sets or alternatively you could just do it by hand.

Comment: As I check it again I see values are there in Table_1.
Datatypes in mapping is string. And I have kept DB type as nchar as the Tables' schema has it as nchar.